# External momenta vs loop momenta in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, specific-reference, virtual-particles

In Peskin and Schroeder's book on QFT, the [second](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_Q84DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT580&lpg=PT580&dq=In%20a%20renormalizable%20theory,%20the%20loop%20integrals%20over%20virtual-particle%20momenta%20are%20always%20dominated%20by%20values%20comparable%20to%20the%20finite%20external%20particle%20momenta.&source=bl&ots=yYtTgx2qha&sig=QodONZzKLTMNYUYgZn9cE2yzH2E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn3u-lx5XUAhVJuo8KHTIRCkMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=In%20a%20renormalizable%20theory%2C%20the%20loop%20integrals%20over%20virtual-particle%20momenta%20are%20always%20dominated%20by%20values%20comparable%20to%20the%20finite%20external%20particle%20momenta.&f=false) paragraph of chapter 12 says,

> In a renormalizable theory, the loop integrals over virtual-particle momenta are always dominated by values comparable to the finite external particle momenta. But why?

What is the meaning of this statement? In particular, since the virtual particle momenta can be arbitrarily large whereas the external particle momenta are finite, I don't understand what do they mean by this statement. Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: What I understand is they say that the loop momentum isn't mostly going to be at the same range as the external momentum, and that's why we can use a cutoff to renormalize. It makes sense to me, because the probability to borrow infinitely big energies from the vacuum is very small.. So the loop momentum is in the same range as the outside momentum.

Comment: I would guess that it means that loop contributions are always dominated by the tree-level diagrams.